# How to change macOS dropdown menu selection behavior for non-matching values?

Tags: keyboard, mail.app, shortcut

I have a dropdown in Apple Mail like so:

[image]

When I open this dropdown, and then I press the `d` key, then the "Drafts" option gets highlighted as expected.

But, when I press the `h` key, the "Important" option gets highlighted, which is unexpected. Similarly, when I press the `z` key, the option "w3c github" gets highlighted, which is also unexpected.

I expect no option to be selected when I make any non-matching keystroke.

What is the logic behind this implementation? It seems arbitrary to me. I also tested Windows which behaves correctly (invalid keystrokes in dropdowns don't select any menu options).

Is there a configuration to change this behaviour to match the behaviour in Windows?

Comment: I changed the title of your question to prevent it from getting closed as some users could have found it a bit too subjective.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is documented somewhere officially but it looks like macOS (at least as of Ventura) uses the alphabetical order of the pressed key character relative to the first letters of the active dropdown menu options in deciding which option to highlight.

If there is no menu option whose first letter is the same as the character for pressed key, then the menu option whose first letter is after but closest to the pressed key in the alphabet is chosen. If there is no menu option whose first letter is the same as or alphabetically after the pressed key, then the menu option closest to the pressed key alphabetically is chosen.

I don't think there is an easy way to change this behavior. The "usual" way to call for and execute a menu option in a program in macOS using a keyboard shortcut is by using the specially assigned universal or program-wise keyboard shortcut such as the Command+C (Copy) universal shortcut or the Mail program-specific Shift+Command+N (Get All New Mail) shortcut.

If there is no shortcut assigned to a menu option and you wish to have one or change the existing one, you can do that by following the instructions given in the "[Use macOS keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/keyboard-shortcuts-mchlp2262/13.0/mac/13.0)" and "[Create keyboard shortcuts for apps on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-apps-mchlp2271/13.0/mac/13.0)" Apple support webpages.

There are also third-party applications which help users customize the keyboard shortcuts on their Macs in case the tools provided by macOS are deemed to be insufficient. You can easily find many of them quickly by searching this site, the App Store or the Internet.

Comment: When I press 'z', the option starting with 'w' is highlighted. So it seems it's not always "after but closest to the pressed key". I am surprised there is no documentation for this behavior, but I appreciate your response.

Comment: Finder windows have always done this too, presumably using a similar 'sort' mechanism. [Oddly, I've never thought to test it's wrong letter behaviour before now, as I usually type the letter[s] I'm looking for, not ones I'm not;)

Comment: @GaurangTandon Yes, you are right. If there is no menu option whose first letter is the same as or alphabetically after the pressed key, then the menu option closest to the pressed key is chosen. Added that to my answer.